# SubQuery execution time : localhost = 2 seconds / server = 98+ seconds

Tags: mysql, subquery

May I ask for some help with a subQuery, please?

When I run the query on my local XAMP mySQL db, the query takes 2 seconds to complete. Yet with an identical db on my webserver the same query takes 98 seconds plus to return the same results.

When I say Identical, the records are exported and inserted from HeidiSQL so I’m sure the dataset is OK. The database DDL, was also created from HeidiSQL, but I’m guessing that I may have missed some crucial step for creating an exact copy of the database.

I have created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/index.html#!9/be104) also using Heidi’s export function. Although I should point out the query executes a lot quicker on the fiddle than in real life.

The query I am executing is …

```
SELECT  d.dayID, d.dayDate, d.item, w.Idx, w.word, w.wordID, w.asize, w.span
FROM words w
    INNER JOIN days d ON w.dayID = d.dayID
    WHERE w.word IN (
            SELECT w1.word
            FROM words w1
                INNER JOIN days d1 ON w1.dayID = d1.dayID
            WHERE d1.dayDate = '2012-02-27'
                AND d1.Item = 'a'
                AND w1.span  = 24
                AND w1.asize = 6
            )
    AND w.span = 24
    AND w.asize = 6
GROUP BY d.dayDate, d.item 
Order by d.dayDate, w.asize DESC, w.Idx;
```

It’s purpose is to return a list of Days and Items from the days table, where there are duplicate words in the word table.

The query above would return results similar to this …

```
dayID   dayDate         item    Idx     word        wordID      asize   span
1974    2012-11-22      B       3       item b      1367339     6       24
4370    2015-03-10      B       1       item b      3024989     6       24
```

Using phpMyAdmin, I added an index to the word field, this made a difference dropping the time from 98 to 46 seconds. But, surely, 46 seconds is too long also ?

Other points to note, the words table in reality contains about 3 million records. Other query (non subquery) run in the blink of an eye. I guess I just suck at subqueries.

May I ask can anyone point me in the right direction for identifying why the query would take so long to execute when on the server ?

Comment: I will try a few tests today and update the Q with some results from Barranka's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should avoid using `IN` when dealing with complex or big subqueries. That's because the `IN` condition must be evaluated *once for each row in the data source*. So, if your data source has 1000 rows and the `IN` condition has 1000 elements, the execution will be something like this:

- For row 1, run the subquery and check if the value is in the subquery result
- For row 2, run the subquery and check if the value is in the subquery result
- ...
- and so on

(needless to say that if the subquery is complex, that will be a huge performance penalty)

So, there are somethings you can do to speed things up:

1. Instead of using `IN`, use `JOIN`
2. Instead of using a subquery, create a temporary table, add the appropriate indexes, and use `JOIN`

I'll deal with option 2. You can substitute the temporary table with the full subquery if you want.

So, let's create a temp table:

```
drop table if exists temp_words;
create temporary table temp_words
    SELECT w1.word
    FROM words w1
        INNER JOIN days d1 ON w1.dayID = d1.dayID
    WHERE d1.dayDate = '2012-02-27'
      AND d1.Item = 'a'
      AND w1.span  = 24
      AND w1.asize = 6;
alter table temp_words
    add index w(word);
```

Now, instead of using `IN`, use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  d.dayID, d.dayDate, d.item, w.Idx, w.word, w.wordID, w.asize, w.span
FROM words w
    INNER JOIN days d 
            ON w.dayID = d.dayID
    INNER JOIN temp_words as w1 -- Replace 'temp_words' with your subquery 
                                -- if you don't want to use a temp table
            ON w.word = w1.word
WHERE w.span = 24
  AND w.asize = 6
GROUP BY d.dayDate, d.item 
Order by d.dayDate, w.asize DESC, w.Idx;
```

I think you'll notice a big performance boost by using `JOIN` instead of `IN`.

Things you must know about temp tables:

1. They behave like normal tables, so you can use them just like you'd use any other table: You can insert, update and delete rows, you can add indexes or alter them in any way you want (or need), and you can drop them if they are no longer useful.
2. They are visible only to the connection that created them. This means that two connections can create temp tables with the same name (but possibly with different structure), and each connection can use it's own "copy".
3. They are dropped once the connection is closed or killed, so you'll have to create them again if you close or kill your connection.

Comment: Wow, what an answer. There is so much to take in and learn. Regarding dropping the subquery ... I would love to. I just find them very confusing and complicated. Thank you. I will try you recommendations and update leave a comment. +1'd for now.

Comment: That is just SQL voodoo. I took the easier option for my test ... that is 'replace temp_words with your subquery' only as it was a quick test. From 98 seconds (my best time) to 0.125 (WTF) seconds with your join. I need to test more with the other information you mentioned. I especially want to check out and read about these 'temp tables' ... I have a feeling they will be very helpful. I had heard of them before, but never felt I had a reason to use them, so I just ignored them. Anyway, accepted your answer and moved you to the top of my 'buy these people a beer' list.

Comment: I think it is courtesy, when someone helps, to view their profile. Often there are ‘extra’ gems to learn there too. I followed the link you provided and whilst agreeing with the content, I have to admit that I too have been guilty of not applying the ‘what have you tried’ principal first. Sometimes, it’s been a case of really not knowing where to start, but other times it has been laziness. It just highlights the importance of effort – even if it goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Johnny Happy to help! Temporary tables can be powerful tools to split big tasks into small steps: they can be used in many "divide-and-conquer" solutions. As for your other comment, I can only say: now that you know about that ["What have you tried"](http://whathaveyoutried.com) approach, use it and pay it forward; that way everybody wins! (And yes, it would be nice to have a beer!)

Comment: Thank you again, Barranka. I've learnt more than I could have hoped to from you. I will try to pay things forward, too. Cheers.